# Seeking cities boundaries of Canada

Tags: shapefile, data, download, canada

I would like to download Canadian cities' borders as shapefiles for clipping satellite imagery for several cities. I could find the US city borders as "Urban Areas" in the following page: https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.2017.html. However I could not find the same data for Canada.

Does anyone know where I can download Canadian city bounds as shapefiles?

Comment: From the internet. Probably some Canadian official source. Or OSM if all fails. What have you searched for?

Comment: I found the cities' boundaries for Us but not for Canada,I only found this website where could not find such data https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/306e5004-534b-4110-9feb-58e3a5c3fd97 I need a shape file with all Canadian cities' Boundaries, if possibly not OSM.

Comment: What have you searched for?

Comment: "Canadian cities borders as shape files", and got this : https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/306e5004-534b-4110-9feb-58e3a5c3fd97 where could not find a shape file of the city borders but of the provinces ...

Comment: So, you didn't bother browsing around that website, or doing additional searches?

Comment: yes I did but all I found and download was at province level administrative boundaries not at city level in shape file in: https://open.canada.ca/en/open-data but I will try another search in the site ...

Comment: I suggest you go for "municipalities", since that is what cities are. There seem to be province-wide data sets, which you will have to filter and combine yourself. Still, it is official data. The reason I am a bit annoying is the lack of detail you put into your question at first, while you actually did some thorough research.

Comment: Look at [census data](https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/catalogue/92-162-X). For MOST of the country the `csd` are the same as municipalities. It is/used to be different for Prince Edward Island and Newfoundland over the country side, where the CSDs are/were bigger and with an ugly name that nobody uses...  Statistics Canada was supposed to drop them and instead use the real name/boundaries, I don't know if they have done it for this year census

Comment: The solution I found is to select "English", "ArGIS (.shp)" for the category of "population centers" at the website : https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm the shape file downloaded appears to be close to urbanized areas

Comment: Hello JGH, thanks a lot, I think the data I was looking for is in the web link you mention but the I had to choose the 2016 Census and from there the "Population centers" if I want to have a shape file where the urbanization nucleus are delimited other categories and the 2020 file give polygons with lager areas than solely the urbanization

Comment: The "population centers" are not municipalities. While they more or less cover urbanized area, they can encompass several municipalities (look at Montreal, which includes Laval, Longueuil, Mirabel and several smaller municipalities) or even Ottawa which also includes Gatineau eventhough it is in a different province.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **City Boundaries Limits** you need the Census Subdivisions dataset in ArcGIS Shapefile format. Use the Cartographic Boundary File.

> https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm

[image]

In QGIS with data labelled
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  for me was a good explanation of the composition of the data but the "Census Subdivision" and might divide into several parts or "Subdivisions" and thus polygons a single population center or urbanization nucleus such as for instance Vancouver and I needed a shape file depicting unique named urbanizations or unique named urbanized areas that is way "population centers" might have a unique polygon per urbanized area, I suppose...

Answer (score -1):

The file I found closer to what I needed, a vectorial (.shp) approximation to the border of urbanizations in Canada, is the lpc_000b16a_e or lpc_000b16a_e.zip (ZIP version, 3,863.0 kb) possible to find at the link recommended by JGH (see the comments above) after choosing 2016 Census and from there, then "Population centers":  https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lpc_000b16a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%20%203863&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lpc_000b16a_e.zip

Example of Vancouver urbanization approximation as vector by the file lpc_000b16a_e:

[image]